# React js Login redirects to dashboard when it get reload

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {

        const obj = {      
            "username": data.username,
            "password": data.password
        }
        
        login.mutate(obj, {
            onSuccess: (response) => {

                localStorage.setItem('token', response?.data?.data?.token)

                if (obj.username === obj.password) {

                    setIsModalOpen(true)    
                    if (***page is reload***) {
                        localStorage.removeItem('token', response?.data?.data?.token)
                        setIsModalOpen(false);
                    }

                } else {
                    navigate('/home')
                }
                
             }, 
            onError: (err) => {
                alert(err?.response?.data?.message)
            }
        })
```

This is my login page when you logged the user and password is valid, the token is fetched
[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDFAU.png)
In my change password modal, when it gets reload it redirects to my dashboard
[Change Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys23H.png)
Here is  my dashboard
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrE0e.png)
What I want is the page is reloaded the token will be deleted then my modal will be closed

I tried look for event listener and how the page reload. but it still redirects to my dashboard.

Comment: What logic you've tried so far for detecting page refresh?